# How to resolve "Metadata Rejected" from itunes connect?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store-connect

My iOS app is in state "Metadata Rejected" as per the Apple Review Guidelines

> 3.2: Apps with placeholder text will be rejected
>   and followed their steps as below:
>
> - Click Edit in the Metadata section
> - Revise the desired metadata values
> - Click "Save" at the bottom of the screen
> - Once you click Save, you will see the "Submit New Metadata" button in the top right. 
>     Click "Submit New Metadata"

I proceeded upto step 3, while I clicked "save", Activity is rotating but not saved, and session got failure, So I can't update the description.

I think, I have to do is "Reject the app and re-upload the app, while re-uploading I will update the description"

Is it right?

Comment: if u re upload ur app,it will take the entire time again(may be 1 week) to valuate ur app.ur case is metadata rejected.so u need to edit ur metadata only.that may take 1 or 2 days to get approved.retry to upadate ur metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Session failures do happen sometimes in iTunes connect - sometimes the data is saved nonetheless, and if not, just try it again (and again and again if necessary), it will work at some point ...

Once the data is saved, you can just push the then appearing "submit new metadata" button. It just happened to me twice last week, so it really does work - and do not re-upload the binary, it really takes the full 7 + days again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TheEye, You said is right, Instead of waiting for 7+days, I done the following:

---> rejected the binary
 ---> then clicked the "Ready to upload binary"
 ---> and then I edited the meta-ata
 ---> and then re-uploaded the binary again to iTunes connect.

Since A fresh upload of binary also will take a week to become "Ready for Sale".